# How To Do Vlookup With Conditional

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I am doing a `Vlookup` on and ads report.  I have the following table:

```
NAME        DELIVERY
AD_NAME_1   inactive
AD_NAME_2   inactive
AD_NAME_3   inactive
AD_NAME_1   active
AD_NAME_1   archived
```

I want to do a `vlookup` by NAME and if any ad with that NAME is "active" I would like to display that.  Otherwise, I want to display that it is "inactive".  How would I do this?

In this example the result would be:

```
AD_NAME_1 is "active
AD_NAME_2 is "inactive"
AD_NAME_3 is "inactive"
```

Comment: how "AD_NAME_2" became "inactive"?

Comment: @player0 updated, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SORT(A1:A), SORT(A1:B, 1, 1, 2, 1), {1, 2}, 0))))
```

[image: 0]